# get value of input element with "id" or "name"

Tags: php, post, methods, input, element

I am trying to learn php and I have seen some videos and tutorials, when creating session variables which values are going to be pulled out from values entered in input elements, the "id" of the input element is the one that matters while when checking if a submit button was clicked is the "name" of the input element what matters?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Register'])) {  //Register is the "name" 
   session_start();
   $Fname = $_POST['first_name'];  //first_name is the "id"
    ...
}
?>
<!doctype html>
...
<form action="" method="post" name="registerform" id="registerform">
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="first_name">

...
<input name="Register" type="submit" id="register" value="submit">
```

Comment: Did you try printing both of them? e.g. `print $_POST['first_name'];` and then `print $_POST['firstname'];`Doing so should tell you which gives you the input value.

Comment: Been done gazillion times

Comment: `$Fname = $_POST['first_name'];` won't give you any value because the input value `name` is `firstname`, you may want to use `$Fname = $_POST['firstname'];`

Comment: In your words, it is the `name` of the input element what matters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Id and Classes are mainly for CSS or JavaScript purpose.Use name for getting the post values `$_POST['firstname']`.

```
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="first_name">
```

Answer (score 11):

Following are my guidelines:

1) Whenever we post a form, only `name` will be considered for getting posted value.
  e.g.

`<input type="text" name="fname" id="first_name"/>`

Here we get `$_POST['fname']` Not `$_POST['first_name']`;

2) Id and classes are there for CSS/JS purposes. Thus if you add whatever class/id attributes to the element,

Only `name` gets posted.

3) In the array `$_POST`, `name` is the `key` and `value` in it is a value.

Comment: Good *my guidelines* :)

Answer (score 3):

$_POST['firstname'] <> $_POST['first_name']

It takse name atribute, not the ID one.
You have to use

```
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
```